# How can I calculate number of days between 2 dates?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a reservation page and a reservation table which contains `reservationstart` column, `reservationend` column and `numofdays` column.

I have determined the number of days between the two dates which a client will select but nothing was stored in the table when I update.

The data type of numofdays was `datatime` but I have changed this to `int`.

I used this first, to declare the start and end date:

```
DayPilotScheduler1.Scale = TimeScale.Manual
Dim start As New Date(Date.Today.Year, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0)
Dim [end] As Date = start.AddYears(1)
```

This is the code for the update:

```
Protected Sub DayPilotScheduler1_EventMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.EventMoveEventArgs)
    Dim id_Renamed As String = e.Value
    Dim start As Date = e.NewStart
    Dim [end] As Date = e.NewEnd
    Dim resource As String = e.NewResource

    Dim message As String = Nothing

    If Not dbIsFree(id_Renamed, start, [end], resource) Then
        message = "The reservation cannot overlap with an existing reservation."
    ElseIf e.OldEnd <= Date.Today Then
        message = "This reservation cannot be changed anymore."
    ElseIf e.OldStart < Date.Today Then
        If e.OldResource <> e.NewResource Then
            message = "The room cannot be changed anymore."
        Else
            message = "The reservation start cannot be changed anymore."
        End If
    ElseIf e.NewStart < Date.Today Then
        message = "The reservation cannot be moved to the past."
    Else
        dbUpdateEvent(id_Renamed, start, [end], resource)
        'message = "Reservation moved.";
    End If

    LoadResourcesAndEvents()
    DayPilotScheduler1.UpdateWithMessage(message)
End Sub

Private Sub dbUpdateEvent(ByVal id As String, ByVal start As Date, ByVal [end] As Date, ByVal resource As String)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionStringLocal").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim numOfDay As Integer = CInt(([end] - start).TotalDays())


        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [Reservation] SET ReservationStart = @start, ReservationEnd = @end, RoomId = @resource,numofday=@numofday WHERE ReservationId = @id", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", [end])
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("resource", resource)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("numofday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numOfDay
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Screenshot of database table structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Math.abs(new Date(timestringone) - new Date(timestringtwo))/(1000*60*60*24))
```

Simply subtracting the dates returns the time in Milliseconds inbetween them. If the first time was before the second time the value is negative, so i used Math.abs to make it absolute. Then we divide trough 1000Milliseconds=1second, 60seconds=1minute, 60minutes=1hour, 24hours=1 day, and floor it to whole days. Requires two valid timestrings (timestringone and timestringtwo) to be given.

This is a javascript solution as youve included the js tag...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the VB.Net but you can easily accomplished it in C# using an object of Type "TimeSpan". For example: let's assume that we want to know the number of days between the start and end. values for the DateTime Type and show it in a Console window, then I may write something like:

```
DateTime start=DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime end=DateTime.MaxValue;
TimeSpan span=end-start;
Console.WriteLine( "There're {0} days between {1} and {2}" , span.TotalDays, start.ToString(), end.ToString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is having problems using the `.Days` property on the `TimeSpan` structure. I think this may help:

```
Dim numOfDay As Integer = CInt(([end] - start).TotalDays())
```

The output is:

```
365
```

Moving onto the use of your parameters, I think you would benefit from using [.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) and specifying the data type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = start
cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.Date).Value = [end]
cmd.Parameters.Add("@resource", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(resource)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@numofday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numOfDay
```

> Note that you may have to change the `SqlDbType`. I've taken an assumption.

I would also implement `Using` for both the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. This for me is just good practice and the code does read better. I would also use the `.Add` overload for all parameters.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionStringLocal").ConnectionString),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [Reservation] SET ReservationStart = @start, ReservationEnd = @end, RoomId = @resource, numofday = @numofday WHERE ReservationId = @id", con)

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = start
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.Date).Value = [end]
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@resource", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(resource)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@numofday", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(([end] - start).TotalDays())

    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If rowsAffected = 0 Then
        'nothing updated
    Else
        'something updated
    End If

End Using
```